# How to cross-compile a native makefile project on OS X for ios?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, makefile, cross-compiling

I have a c/c++ lib that originally targets win/osx/ubuntu. The lib source is available and I want to compile it for ios.

Many of the [discussions](http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/how-to-cross-compiling-libraries-for-ios-armv6armv7i386/) about this scenario are based on the assumption of an automake configure script and are not very helpful, as the lib is a native makefile project.

I also tried to add the lib to Xcode 5.1 as an external target, then became clueless of how to specify build settings(Base SDK, target device, etc.) for it(I don't use Xcode often). Seems external target in Xcode does not have relative settings?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it is opensource, kindly link the location in your question and I can take a peek. I *think* you want to build a universal framework ([many articles on it, one here](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework)). But the difficulty in that is to-be-seen.

Comment: Hi WhozCraig, thanks for the info. The lib itself is proprietary, but like any other opensource libs it has dependencies of boost and some other image libs. I was just trying to create a 'ios_makefile' from the existed osx_makefile, by replacing the CFLAGS -IXXX options with headers from iPhoneOS7.1.sdk, but failed with a linker error said linking against /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib. I am quite foreign to osx/ios stuff like '-framework', but I guess the error is because the target binary has to link to ios system libs rather than osx libs, is this understanding correct?

Comment: Pretty much. Building iOS frameworks always was a pain, and apple didn't help in making it easier. I sometimes think they want us all writing apps and not libs (like that job is theirs alone). I haven't done it (built a dynamic framework for iOS) for two versions now. Maybe they made it easier. Since Xcode 5.1 and the latest iOS. I'd have to try it (again).

Answer (score 1):

To compile C/C++ for iOS, you need to pretty much compile it as you normally would, except you need to use `clang` / `clang++` as the compiler and specify the sysroot, the arch and the iOS version.

You can get the iphone sysroot by running:

```
xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path
```

So something like this:

```
clang++ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk -arch arm64 -arch armv7 -arch armv7s -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 file.cpp
```